# Android automated test cases in python using appium framework

Tags: python, automation, appium

this is a text shot from error message on cmd appeared when trying to execute test cases in python ..
error in line 19: ***self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)*** in setup function

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 19, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 36, in **init**
    super(WebDriver, self).**init**(command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in **init**
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error: com.app./.Activities.StartActivity never started. Current: com.app./.Activities.Login.LoginActivity)

---

Answer (score 1):

what are your desired capabilities?

try to specify

'appWaitActivity': '*' in your desired capabilities,

it will launch your application and then you can find out in appium logs what exact activity was launched, and then you can replace * with found activity name.